# Django passing multiple models to a template

Tags: python, django, templates, model

I'm developing Django app for first time. How can I pass multiple models to a template

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.utils import timezone
from LastAlly.models import Article, Episode


class IndexView(ListView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:3]
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from LastAlly.views import IndexView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), ),
]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "pass multiple models to a template"?

Comment: I need to use Episode model to index template.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the view's methods, in this case you can edit the [`.get_context_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) method:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:3]
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['episode_objects'] = Episode.objects.....
        return context
```

Then in your template will have a `{{ episode_objects }}` variable with the Episode model objects.

Comment: That's I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Crownstyle If you found this helpful consider accept this answer to help someone else with the same problem.